# Using numpy einsum to perform high dimensional subtraction broadcasting

Tags: numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I'm having troubles in using a broadcasting subtraction. My problem is the following. I have an array `x` of shape `[L,N]`, where L is an integer and N is the number of variables of my problem.
I need to compute a `[L,N,N]` array where at each element `l,i,j` it contains `x[l,i]-x[l,j]`.
If L=1 this is equivalent to run broadcasting on subtraction: `x-x.T`

For example here with L=1 and N=3:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,2,4]])
x-x.T
```

However, if one increases the dimension L things become more complicated and enter the realm of the `np.einsum` function.
So I tried to recreate my example, in the case L=2, where I've replicated the two rows. What I'd expect is to get a 2x3x3 array with two 3x3 matrices with equal elements.

```
x = np.array([[0,2,4],[0,2,4]])
n = 3
k = 2
X = np.zeros([k,n,n])
for l in range(k):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            X[l,i,j] = x[l,i]-x[l,j]
print(X)
```

which returns

```
[[[ 0. -2. -4.]
[ 2.  0. -2.]
[ 4.  2.  0.]]

[[ 0.  -2. -4.]
[2.  0. -2.]
[ 4.  2.  0.]]]
```

But how to make this with numpy einsum? I can only obtain the product:

```
np.einsum('ki,kj->kij',x,-x)
```

Are there specific examples of numpy batched subtractions or additions with increased dimension?

Comment: `einsum` is an extension of the matrix product - multiply certain combinations of axes, and sum some the resulting ones.  It doesn't implement other operators.

Comment: You don't need einsum. Simply extend and subtract - `x[:,:,None]-x[:,None,:]` or `x[...,None]-x[:,None]`.